# Reusing a method of the Parent class in the child class while using the variables of the child class

Tags: java

I must create a programm in Java. This program must select randomly among several games. All those game must ask one or more parameters, those paramaters are always character string. When a game is selected, it will analyze and test one ore more parameters to find out if the player win or lose and display the score. Current games are palindrome and anagram detector.

I created a parent class Games, in this class I have a .run() method which contain all the methods which make the game work.

When I create an instance of a game (palindrome or anagram), I would like to know if I can use .run() method on each instance with instance variables.

```
Palindrome palindrome = new Palindrome();
palindrome.run();
```

Here, .run() is not defined in palindrome class, but is a method of parent class Games. When I call it, it takes variables of parent class. I would like the variables called to be those of palindrome class.

Comment: Create a constructor in your parent class with parameters to set the values of the instance fields.

Comment: You will have to override the run method in the Palindrome and Anagram subclasses.

Comment: So I must override run method ? 
I can't just use parent .run() method with instance variables ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.
No need to Override .run() method here, I think it is not the right solution when you try to use POO way.

I left my .run() method, which run a game with all the methods needed, in my abstract parent class. Then I modified methods in my parent class by abstract methods and overrided them in all my child classes.
So when I create an instance of my parent class, run() method is owned by parent class.
I think it's the right way to use polymorphism.

Example:

```
public abstract class Games {
  public void run() {
    initGame();
  }

  /* 
    Several abstract methods
    Or not if method is generic, like count unknown parameters for each game
  */
 }

public class Game1 extends Games {

  // Some variables
  int nbParam = 2;      

  @Override
  /* 
     Override abstract methods in parent class like getDescription(), getNbParam(), 
     initGame(), setScore(), getScore(), etc...
  */
 }
```

So, when I create an instance of Game1 and call my method run, the variables are Game1  variables.
There is not just one solution, but I think it's the right way to use polymorphism.